# Having extremely low bounce rates with Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics, rate, bounce

I wonder why I am suddenly getting extremely low rejection (bounce rates) in Google Analytics.
Something like 0.18% or even lower, and although I'd love it to be true, it is clearly a bad reading or something.
Has someone seen this kind of problem?
Any ideias?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because is not related to programming

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have 2 times the tracking code on page or otherwise send two interactions together, for example a pageview and an event.